# Add header text to bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, acm

I want to add an extra paragraph into my bibliography section, under the title, before the first references.

[image]

Is this even remotely possible, or do I need to look for another way around?

I'm using the [acmsmall.cls](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) layout - my bibliography is currently built like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

%%%I want to add a statement here!

\bibitem{G}
Carretero, J., Isaila, F., Kermarrec, A. M., Taïani, F., \& Tirado, J. M. 
(2012, June). 
Geology: Modular georecommendation in gossip-based social networks. 
In Distributed Computing Systems (ICDCS), 2012 IEEE 32nd International Conference on (pp. 637-646). 
IEEE.


\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\thebibliography` to add the text before the list used; I defined `\AddNote` to typeset the text:

```
\documentclass{acmsmall}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\AddNote[1]{\def\@addnote{#1}}
\providecommand\@addnote{}
\def\thebibliography#1{%
    \footnotesize
    \refsection*{{\refname}
        \@mkboth{\uppercase{\refname}}{\uppercase{\refname}}%
    }
    \@addnote\par
    \list{}{
        \settowidth\labelwidth{}
        \leftmargin0pt
        \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
        \itemindent -\bibindent
        \itemsep2pt
        \parsep \z@
        \usecounter{enumi}%
    }%
    \let\newblock\@empty
    \sloppy
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\AddNote{And here's the text that will be added to the bibliography, right after the title but before the first entry. We add some more text here.}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{G}
Carretero, J., Isaila, F., Kermarrec, A. M., Taïani, F., \& Tirado, J. M. 
(2012, June). 
Geology: Modular georecommendation in gossip-based social networks. 
In Distributed Computing Systems (ICDCS), 2012 IEEE 32nd International Conference on (pp. 637-646). 
IEEE.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code simplifies using a patch to the command:

```
\documentclass{acmsmall}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\AddNote[1]{\def\@addnote{#1}}
\providecommand\@addnote{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
  {\list}
  {\@addnote\par\list}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\AddNote{And here's the text that will be added to the bibliography, right after the title but before the first entry. We add some more text here.}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{G}
Carretero, J., Isaila, F., Kermarrec, A. M., Taïani, F., \& Tirado, J. M. 
(2012, June). 
Geology: Modular georecommendation in gossip-based social networks. 
In Distributed Computing Systems (ICDCS), 2012 IEEE 32nd International Conference on (pp. 637-646). 
IEEE.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @gonzalo-medina i'd like to learn how substitute the `\AddNote{}` command with an environment `AddHeader`. Something like `\begin{AddHeader} <header text> \end{AddHeader}` instead of `\AddNote{<header text>}`. i read your thesis about `background` and `fancypar` packages but i can't do it.

Comment: @skpblack feel free to open a fresh new question as a follow-up to this one.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, should you be using `biblatex` is to either print the bibliography without a heading and make your own heading and note:

```
\section*{References}
This note will appear before the bibliography...
\printbibliography[heading=none,...]
```

...or use the `prenote=...` option with a `\defbibnote` to define your note.

```
\defbibnote{intro}{This note will appear before the bibliography...}
\printbibliography[prenote=intro,...]
```

See page 71 of the [biblatex documentation](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).